# Client socket and Server Socket bound to the same port

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have an IoT device (most likely across NAT), which should communicate with server (on internet), and the server should be able to send commands to the device. Here's the high level communication details:

1. IoT device will send KeepAlive packet from port 9000 (say) to the server on a port 8000 (say). The server now has the port and IP (say Cp and Cip) which it could use to start a connection back with IoT device if needed.
2. Server is obviously listening for connections on port 8000. So Server has a server-socket to listen to IoT device's keepalives
3. The KeepAlive packets are sent periodically, and the connection are closed once the server returns OK. This is to ensure a socket is not kept open, saving resources on both server and IoT device.
4. Now, say I want to send some command to the IoT device, in that case, I want to open a socket connection from the Server on port 8000, and send packet to Cip, Cp.
5. The IoT device should receive this packet on its port 9000. For that to happen, the IoT device should open a server socket to accept these connections.

As we can see, both client and server have to open the server socket on a particular port, and occasionally there's a requirement to create a client socket on that port to send some data.

Would TCP work with above scenario? I'm just confused if Client socket and Server Socket could be bound to the same port?

Please suggest

## EDIT 1:

- I deliberately have chosen above design since keeping IoT device to server connection open all time does not scale. Say I have millions of IoT devices on the field, I'll need to load balance the connections now.
- The server to IoT device (backward) connection is only to ensure the commands are immediately send. The forward connection (IoT device to server) is only created to send the keepalives. It would be done periodically (may be 5-10 mins apart)

## EDIT 2:

The reason for a fixed port (8000) is this: The NAT opens up hole for reverse communication only from the destination port where the keepalive packet was received. So the reverse packet can be sent from a port X on server to IoT device only if a packet had been received from IoT device on that port.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your setup fully but maybe your are doing it overly complex. Why not simply open a TCP connection from IoT client to the server? This TCP connection can be used to send data from client to server but also from server to client. It can be used to send explicit Keep Alive message or just use the keep-alive mechanism built into TCP. And since it is open from the client (behind NAT) to a server (on the internet) it should have no problems with NAT which you would have if you are trying to create a new connection from server to client.

Comment: Why does the device require a remote port of 8000 when connected to by a client? Is this requirement real? It doesn't seem likely. Nor does the requirement that the device act as a server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Letting a connection remain open would mean if I have 1 million of such IoT devices on the field, then the server would need to keep those many open connections.

Comment: @EJP The IoT device needs to connect to server port 8000, since the server needs to know the Ip+Port for client. With (IP, Port) it can from its port 8000 make direct connection from to client

Comment: *Non sequitur.* It does not follow from the fact that the IoT device connects to the server that the server also needs to connect back to the client, let alone that it needs source port 8000 to do so. You haven't actually clarified any of this. I suggest you have misunderstood.

Comment: @EJP I understand that its not necessary for server to connect back to client. But lets say that is needed. It saves on resources in case you have millions of such IoT devices on the field. Keeping connection open all the time would require enormous load balancing servers. The requirement to open a back connection is to ensure that commands are immediately received from IoT devices.

Comment: And where does the requirement for the source port 8000 come from? Do you realize that this will probably mean your server can only connect to one IoT device at a time? It isn't a credible requirement, and nor is it feasible.

Comment: If your IOT devices are behind NAT you can't trivially call them back, especially not if you close any connection they had.

Comment: @EJP Thats just a random number from my head. If the server had to send commands (and hence 'reverse' connection) to multiple IoT devices, why would it restrict to just one? Why can't I create multiple  'client' sockets on the server, bind them to port 8000, and connect them to IoT device's (Cip, Cp)? A connection is between two end sockets, I dont see any reason why it would restrict to just one IoT. Can you tell me if there's any obvious mistake in my reasoning

Comment: @CodeCaster: What cannot reverse connection happen? I've created a similar thing in UDP, it works there. Are you suggesting that NAT mapping software is smart enough to check for TCP connection end packets and remove the mapping?

Comment: *What* is just a random number from your head? Do you mean 8000? I don't care about that any more than you do. My question is why do you think you need a fixed source port *at all?* You *don't,* and you can't do it. You've been asked this many times. You have not provided a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @EJP: Okay, I understand what you're asking. The reason for a fixed port is this: The NAT opens up hole for reverse communication only from the destination port where the keepalive packet was received. So the reverse packet can be sent from a port X on server to IoT device only if a packet had been received from IoT device on that port.